# python: extract raw value from multi-encapsulated dictionary

Tags: python

I want to  extract  string "GROUP" from 2 level encapsulated dictionary.

```
dict = {'instance1' : {'runType' : 'GROUP'},
        'instance2' : { 'runType' : 'PROCESS'}}
```

If i access runType of `instance1` with  obviuos way `dict['instance1']['runType']`, then i get the string `['GROUP']`. I also tried `dict['instance1'].get('runType', 'Null')`, with hope that `.get` will return raw string `"GROUP"`, but that did not happened.

Is there any other short way to get pure string data from `X>1` level of dictionary without  `str()` and then `strip()` etc.?

--------------Solution---------------

dict['instance1']['runType'][0] will return pure GROUP string

Comment: i want to have pure string without square brackets and quotes. i want to compare it further with other text string . Regarding name - disregard it , i do not name it in script this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got  correct answer from  friend. ['GROUP'] is a list with 1 member. 
So , dict['instance1']['runType'][0]  will return pure GROUP.
Thank you everybody!

Comment: If this answer is right, then the dict you gave us is wrong: the one you gave us had `dict['instance1']['runType'] == 'GROUP'`, not `['GROUP']`.  If you give people the wrong data, then they'll come up with right answers to the wrong problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
extraced_string = dict['instance1']['runType']
```

is the best solution. `extracted_string` now contains `GROUP`, and you can use and manipulate it as you like. Also, you shouldn't name your dictionary dict because that's the name of a built-in class.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me

```
>>> dict = {'instance1' : {'runType' : 'GROUP'} , 'instance2' : { 'runType' : 'PROCESS'}}
>>> dict['instance1']['runType']
'GROUP'
```

Comment: It do not show square brackets in on-the-fly interpretor. In script it will return you ['GROUP'] . Also i want single quotes disappear.